# Help to recognize math formula

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Have someone idea what is this formula and what is it supposed to do?

$${C}^k_v = \alpha\beta\sqrt{\frac{\sum\left(v^4 - \frac{\sum v^4}{n}\right)^2}{(n-1)\left(\frac{\sum v^4}{n}\right)^2}}$$

All I know is that ⍺ and β are likely two integers

Found this formula on those pictures [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRqU9.jpg) [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R72K.jpg)

Comment: Why not use context from the surrounding text?

Comment: The notation is rather illogical, as $k$ seems to play no role. This said, we have something proportional to the variation coefficient of $v^2$. Tell us what $\alpha,\beta$ and $v$ are.

Comment: Where did you find this formula?

Comment: It might be the product moment correlation coefficient formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [strange soviet relict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEvlF.jpg) meanwhile in Minsk. But nobody knows what does it means

Comment: These appear to be the same or similar images to those given in the Question.  It does not qualify as an Answer.  Please review [How do I write a good answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer. It is probably part of the "socialist realism" artistic current that dominated the former communist countries for decades, prior to the sequence of revolutions at the end of the '80s. It is most probably a meaningless formula, its only purpose being to symbolise scientific knowledge and technology, two themes very dear to the communist ideology and propaganda. I hope this answer doesn't get deleted, since it says (very succintly, this is true) exactly what deserves to be said in this context: a meaningless Soviet relic.